# Restkit compatibility in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, restkit

when I tried to include RestKit to my project in iOS 7 Platform, I got error <RestKit/RestKit.h> file not found..

I followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial
and I did exactly the same thing, but I used iOS 7 as my base platform..

I tried the example project inside restKit folder, but used iOS 7,
then I got same error...

Is there any compatibility issue in iOS 7? 
if yes, can anyone recommend me alternate framework?

Answer (score 0):

after strugling...

i solved it by compiling Restkit in its own project,,, then continue including to my own project

and its work..

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you followed is really old. You should look at [this](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#installation) for a guide on how to install RestKit. Ensure you're using the most recent version (don't start using 0.10 now...). The base [RestKit Github page](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) contains a number of examples and the code contains lots of tests that you can look at.

RestKit should basically always be included in your project as a reference to the RestKit project. The current version doesn't have any compatibility issues.